# Unable to enter into BIOS setup

Tags: boot, dual-boot, hp, bios

I have hp-n003tx laptop. Recently I have changed my 1TB HDD to 1TB SSD(crucial company) and removed optical drive and connected HDD in that place. I have windows installed on my SSD. Few days back I have installed Ubuntu on HDD. Now every time I switch on my system I am taken directly to windows. And I wanted to enter into Ubuntu by turning off secureboot. For that I tried pressing esc key and it took me to all option which has boot option and BIOS setup. f9 is key for boot option and f10 for BIOS setup. Now I wanted to turn off my secure boot option. When I press f10 (key for BIOS setup) it doesn't enter into BIOS setup instead it will be in the same page but if I press f9 (boot option) it gave me all the boot option. Please suggest some solution to go into BIOS setup to turnoff secureboot. Thanks.

Comment: This question is not about Ubuntu. Getting into BIOS setup happens before Winsows or Ubuntu or any OS is loaded. This is a problem with BIOS.

Comment: Yeah I meant to say how I wanted to setup my system by dual booting. Just gave a simple example.